# Difference between readline vs fread/fgets in php

Tags: php, io, readline, fgets, fread

I have always used `readline` in my console commands before, but today I've come across the `fread` and `fgets` functions and my question is: what is the difference in using these two approaches:

```
// first
$inputLine = readline();

// second
$inputLine = fgets(STDIN);
```

they both do pretty much the same, do they not?

Comment: Huh, I'm so not familiar with `readline()` in php ... I've only ever used `fgets()` ;) You could write up a benchmark test, and see if theres really any big difference. Otherwise, it may end up being just which you prefer.

Comment: the file pointer makes the difference, but i am not really familiar with them right now, more info: http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgets.php http://php.net/manual/en/function.readline.php

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The only possible difference I can think of is just that `readline()` takes no arguments and can only read input from `STDIN` by default, whilst `fgets()` can take any `resource` to read from. So, in other words `readline()` is a synonym to `fgets` with the first predefined argument, like, for instance, `fprintf()` and `printf()`.

Consider the following:

```
fprintf(STDOUT, "hello!");
printf("hello!);
```

This is quite common in php standard library.

Answer (score 1):

readline() reads input from STDIN by default, while fgets() reads from any resource. Also, readline() takes more time to execute than fgets()

Answer (score 0):

fgets is far faster then the readline. I don't exactly know why, nevertheles I can give you a bit of benchmarking.

I often participate solving problems on codeforces.com. On one of the problem I had time limit issue(when solving with PHP), I was using readline and the time for solution was more than 2 sec. After I replace readline-s with fgets the solving time was 400ms.

So fgets is pretty fast.

Answer (score 0):

From [the readline docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.readline.php):

> The readline functions implement an interface to the GNU Readline
> library. These are functions that provide editable command lines. An
> example being the way Bash allows you to use the arrow keys to insert
> characters or scroll through command history.

`readline` takes a single argument which is the `$prompt` string and it also trims the newline for you.  Additionally, the extension functions feature a command history like bash which could allow you to use arrow keys to scroll through previous entries, the ability to do completion and more. As others habve noted in previous answers, the additional functionality does add a bit of overhead so could be slower.

`fgets` is a bit more basic and simply gets input from a file pointer.

Answer (score 0):

Another difference than those listed here I found is that `fgets()`, unlike `readline()` can't read some utf-8 characters with accents like **'é'** or **'è'**.
It means you have to be careful using `fgets()` because if you could have to use languages like spanish or french it can involve errors.